# JavaScript DOM: How do I tell JS to createElement('p') that says something according to the value in a json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, if-statement

how do I tell JS to createElement('p') that says survived if a boolean array value in a JSON says "1" and if it says "0" to say deceased?
**I need it to create that p element that says "survived" if it the value "survived" in the JSON says 1 or "deceased" if it says 0.
This is one of the many people in the JSON:

```
'use strict';
let passengers = [{
        "PassengerId": 1,
        "Survived": 0,
        "Pclass": 3,
        "Name": "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",
        "Sex": "male",
        "Age": 22,
        "SibSp": 1,
        "Parch": 0,
        "Ticket": "A/5 21171",
        "Fare": 7.25,
        "Cabin": "",
        "Embarked": "S"
    },
//this is my DOM js:

 'use strict';
const seccCards = document.querySelector('#sctCards');
const inputFiltro = document.querySelector('#txtFiltro');
const imprimirCards = () => {
    seccCards.innerHTML = '';
    let filtro = inputFiltro.value.toLowerCase();
    passengers.forEach(obj_passenger => {
        if (obj_passenger.Name.toLowerCase().includes(filtro) || obj_passenger.PassengerId.toLowerCase().includes(filtro)) {
            let card = document.createElement('div');
            card.classList.add('card');
            let passengerbeen = document.createElement('h2');
            passengerbeen.innerText = obj_passenger.Name;
            let passengerF = document.createElement('p');
            if (obj_passenger.Survived == 1) {
                passengerF = sobrevivio;
            } else {
                passengerF = fallecido;
            }
            passengerF.innerHTML = obj_passenger.Survived;

            card.appendChild(passengerbeen);
            card.appendChild(passengerF);
            seccCards.appendChild(card);
        }

    });
};
inputFiltro.addEventListener('keyup', imprimirCards);
imprimirCards();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple if statement with a variable. If they survived, set the variable to `"survived"`, otherwise set it to `"deceased"`. Instead of setting the `p` directly, set the innerHTML of it based on the variable.

```
let passengerF = document.createElement('p');
let survivalStatus;
if (obj_passenger.Survived == 1) {
    survivalStatus = "sobrevivio";
} else {
    survivalStatus = "fallecido";
}
passengerF.innerHTML = survivalStatus;
```